# Classic ASP .loadXML(XMLstring) reads out blank?

Tags: xml, parsing, soap, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using classic ASP to parse SOAP XML notifications sent from the eBay api. I am POSTing myself a test example SOAP message from the api documentation. I am able to receive the string of XML data. When I convert the data to string and output xmlString into a text file, the received XML is in there.

When I loadXML(xmlString) into the DOMDocument object and try to output it, all I get is 3 blank lines. Im trying to loop through the elements and parse them, but it appears to be blank inside the DOM object, as I am getting Object Required errors on the lines looking for nodes.

Here is my code, along with the XML message I am POSTing (using Postmaster app) A little guidance would be appreciated!

```vb
<%
Function BytesToStr(bytes)
    Dim Stream
    Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        Stream.Open
        Stream.Write bytes
        Stream.Position = 0
        Stream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
        Stream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
        BytesToStr = Stream.ReadText
        Stream.Close
    Set Stream = Nothing
End Function


Dim isPost: isPost = (UCase(Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") & "") = "POST")

'Is it a HTTP POST?
If isPost Then

    If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then
        Dim lngBytesCount, xmlString
        lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
        xmlString = BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))


        Dim xdoc
        set xdoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
        xdoc.async = false
        xdoc.loadXML(xmlString)

        call xdoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'")

        '**I commented this next part out because I was getting Error:Object Requred
        '**I couldnt get any XML from xdoc to print at all  
        '**see below: WriteLine(xdoc.xml)    
        'Dim node
        'For Each node in xdoc.selectSingleNode("/soapenv:Body/GetItemResponse").ChildNodes
        '   sResult = sResult & node.xml        
        'Next


        dim fs, tfile
        set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set tfile=fs.OpenTextFile("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ASPtest\_notification3.txt", 8, True)
        tfile.WriteLine(xdoc.xml)
        tfile.WriteLine("")

        tfile.Close
        set tfile=nothing
        set fs=nothing
    End If
  'Let sender know we have received and processing the message.
  Response.Status = "200 OK"
Else
  'Return method not allowed
  Response.Status = "405 Method Not Allowed"
End If
Response.End
%>
```

Sample SOAP message posted (from postman app):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ebl:RequesterCredentials soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
        xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <ebl:NotificationSignature xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Z2yhKdKmS0Ga5VPmLDOAlg==</
          ebl:NotificationSignature>
    </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <Timestamp>2008-02-13T03:47:28.106Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack>Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID>137541140</CorrelationID>
      <Version>553</Version>
      <Build>e553_core_Bundled_6057805_R1</Build>
      <NotificationEventName>ItemSold</NotificationEventName>
      <RecipientUserID>Seller1</RecipientUserID>
      <Item>
        <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
        <BuyerProtection>ItemEligible</BuyerProtection>
        <BuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">10.0</BuyItNowPrice>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <GiftIcon>0</GiftIcon>
        <HitCounter>NoHitCounter</HitCounter>
        <ItemID>250000627102</ItemID>
        <ListingDetails>
          <Adult>false</Adult>
          <BindingAuction>false</BindingAuction>
          <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
          <ConvertedBuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">10.0</ConvertedBuyItNowPrice>
          <ConvertedStartPrice currencyID="USD">1.0</ConvertedStartPrice>
          <ConvertedReservePrice currencyID="USD">0.0</ConvertedReservePrice>
          <HasReservePrice>false</HasReservePrice>
          <StartTime>2008-02-13T03:42:45.000Z</StartTime>
          <EndTime>2008-02-13T03:43:32.000Z</EndTime>
          <ViewItemURL>http://cgi.qa-api012.qa.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&amp;item=250000627102&amp;category=1463</ViewItemURL>
          <HasUnansweredQuestions>false</HasUnansweredQuestions>
          <HasPublicMessages>false</HasPublicMessages>
          <ExpressListing>false</ExpressListing>
          <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://cgi.qa-api012.qa.ebay.com/Test-Item-Won-Sold-notify_W0QQitemZ250000627102QQcategoryZ1463QQcmdZViewItem</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
        </ListingDetails>
        <ListingDuration>Days_5</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
        <Location>San Jose, CA</Location>
        <PaymentMethods>PaymentSeeDescription</PaymentMethods>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>ve2@aol.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <PrimaryCategory>
          <CategoryID>1463</CategoryID>
          <CategoryName>Collectibles:Trading Cards:Phone Cards</CategoryName>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <PrivateListing>false</PrivateListing>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ReservePrice currencyID="USD">0.0</ReservePrice>
        <ReviseStatus>
          <ItemRevised>false</ItemRevised>
        </ReviseStatus>
        <Seller>
          <AboutMePage>false</AboutMePage>
          <Email>seller@email.com</Email>
          <FeedbackScore>100</FeedbackScore>
          <PositiveFeedbackPercent>98.1</PositiveFeedbackPercent>
          <FeedbackPrivate>false</FeedbackPrivate>
          <FeedbackRatingStar>Turquoise</FeedbackRatingStar>
          <IDVerified>false</IDVerified>
          <eBayGoodStanding>true</eBayGoodStanding>
          <NewUser>false</NewUser>
          <RegistrationDate>2004-02-23T23:50:13.000Z</RegistrationDate>
          <Site>US</Site>
          <Status>Confirmed</Status>
          <UserID>Seller1</UserID>
          <UserIDChanged>false</UserIDChanged>
          <UserIDLastChanged>2004-02-23T23:48:54.000Z</UserIDLastChanged>
          <VATStatus>NoVATTax</VATStatus>
          <SellerInfo>
            <AllowPaymentEdit>true</AllowPaymentEdit>
            <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
            <CIPBankAccountStored>false</CIPBankAccountStored>
            <GoodStanding>true</GoodStanding>
            <MerchandizingPref>OptIn</MerchandizingPref>
            <QualifiesForB2BVAT>false</QualifiesForB2BVAT>
            <SellerLevel>None</SellerLevel>
            <StoreOwner>false</StoreOwner>
            <ExpressEligible>false</ExpressEligible>
            <ExpressWallet>false</ExpressWallet>
            <SafePaymentExempt>true</SafePaymentExempt>
          </SellerInfo>
          <MotorsDealer>false</MotorsDealer>
        </Seller>
        <SellingStatus>
          <BidCount>2</BidCount>
          <BidIncrement currencyID="USD">0.25</BidIncrement>
          <ConvertedCurrentPrice currencyID="USD">1.25</ConvertedCurrentPrice>
          <CurrentPrice currencyID="USD">1.25</CurrentPrice>
          <HighBidder>
            <AboutMePage>false</AboutMePage>
            <EIASToken>nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2PrA2dj6wJkoWoCJaGoAmdj6x9nY+seQ==</EIASToken>
            <Email>buyer@email.com</Email>
            <FeedbackScore>5</FeedbackScore>
            <PositiveFeedbackPercent>100.0</PositiveFeedbackPercent>
            <FeedbackPrivate>false</FeedbackPrivate>
            <FeedbackRatingStar>None</FeedbackRatingStar>
            <IDVerified>false</IDVerified>
            <eBayGoodStanding>true</eBayGoodStanding>
            <NewUser>false</NewUser>
            <RegistrationDate>2004-02-24T07:00:00.000Z</RegistrationDate>
            <Site>US</Site>
            <Status>Confirmed</Status>
            <UserID>Buyer1</UserID>
            <UserIDChanged>false</UserIDChanged>
            <UserIDLastChanged>2004-02-24T07:00:00.000Z</UserIDLastChanged>
            <VATStatus>NoVATTax</VATStatus>
            <BuyerInfo>
              <ShippingAddress>
                <Country>US</Country>
                <PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
              </ShippingAddress>
            </BuyerInfo>
            <UserAnonymized>false</UserAnonymized>
          </HighBidder>
          <LeadCount>0</LeadCount>
          <MinimumToBid currencyID="USD">1.5</MinimumToBid>
          <QuantitySold>1</QuantitySold>
          <ReserveMet>true</ReserveMet>
          <SecondChanceEligible>true</SecondChanceEligible>
          <ListingStatus>Completed</ListingStatus>
        </SellingStatus>
        <ShippingDetails>
          <AllowPaymentEdit>true</AllowPaymentEdit>
          <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
          <InsuranceOption>NotOffered</InsuranceOption>
          <SalesTax>
            <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
            <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
          </SalesTax>
          <ThirdPartyCheckout>false</ThirdPartyCheckout>
          <TaxTable/>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ShipToLocations>US</ShipToLocations>
        <Site>US</Site>
        <StartPrice currencyID="USD">1.0</StartPrice>
        <TimeLeft>PT0S</TimeLeft>
        <Title>Test Item{Won/Sold} notify</Title>
        <HitCount>0</HitCount>
        <GetItFast>false</GetItFast>
        <PostalCode>
        </PostalCode>
        <PictureDetails>
          <PhotoDisplay>None</PhotoDisplay>
        </PictureDetails>
        <ProxyItem>false</ProxyItem>
      </Item>
    </GetItemResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: is it because i, for some reason, converted the string to iso-8859-1 and the SOAP XML needs to be in utf-8? ill test tomorrow

Comment: Yes, that is probably the issue that `BytesToStr()` function needs to be modified to fit your requirement, you can't just use it "as is". Try changing `Stream.Charset = "UTF-8"`.

Comment: I was wrong it was the XML parse failing on whitespace caused by hard wrapping in the XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after testing your code it isn't the `Charset` property causing the problem *(but I would make sure it is set to `UTF-8` anyway)*.

The issue is the XML failing to parse and when checking the `parseError` found this;

> -1072896749 - Whitespace is not allowed at this location.

Then I took a look at the XML you posted and it does have some hard wrapping in there which I removed and tested again, this time it succeeded.

Modified XML *(removed hard wrapping)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ebl:RequesterCredentials soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"  xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <ebl:NotificationSignature xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Z2yhKdKmS0Ga5VPmLDOAlg==</ebl:NotificationSignature>
    </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <Timestamp>2008-02-13T03:47:28.106Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack>Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID>137541140</CorrelationID>
      <Version>553</Version>
      <Build>e553_core_Bundled_6057805_R1</Build>
      <NotificationEventName>ItemSold</NotificationEventName>
      <RecipientUserID>Seller1</RecipientUserID>
      <Item>
        <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
        <BuyerProtection>ItemEligible</BuyerProtection>
        <BuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">10.0</BuyItNowPrice>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <GiftIcon>0</GiftIcon>
        <HitCounter>NoHitCounter</HitCounter>
        <ItemID>250000627102</ItemID>
        <ListingDetails>
          <Adult>false</Adult>
          <BindingAuction>false</BindingAuction>
          <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
          <ConvertedBuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">10.0</ConvertedBuyItNowPrice>
          <ConvertedStartPrice currencyID="USD">1.0</ConvertedStartPrice>
          <ConvertedReservePrice currencyID="USD">0.0</ConvertedReservePrice>
          <HasReservePrice>false</HasReservePrice>
          <StartTime>2008-02-13T03:42:45.000Z</StartTime>
          <EndTime>2008-02-13T03:43:32.000Z</EndTime>
          <ViewItemURL>http://cgi.qa-api012.qa.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&amp;item=250000627102&amp;category=1463</ViewItemURL>
          <HasUnansweredQuestions>false</HasUnansweredQuestions>
          <HasPublicMessages>false</HasPublicMessages>
          <ExpressListing>false</ExpressListing>
          <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://cgi.qa-api012.qa.ebay.com/Test-Item-Won-Sold-notify_W0QQitemZ250000627102QQcategoryZ1463QQcmdZViewItem</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
        </ListingDetails>
        <ListingDuration>Days_5</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
        <Location>San Jose, CA</Location>
        <PaymentMethods>PaymentSeeDescription</PaymentMethods>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>ve2@aol.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <PrimaryCategory>
          <CategoryID>1463</CategoryID>
          <CategoryName>Collectibles:Trading Cards:Phone Cards</CategoryName>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <PrivateListing>false</PrivateListing>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ReservePrice currencyID="USD">0.0</ReservePrice>
        <ReviseStatus>
          <ItemRevised>false</ItemRevised>
        </ReviseStatus>
        <Seller>
          <AboutMePage>false</AboutMePage>
          <Email>seller@email.com</Email>
          <FeedbackScore>100</FeedbackScore>
          <PositiveFeedbackPercent>98.1</PositiveFeedbackPercent>
          <FeedbackPrivate>false</FeedbackPrivate>
          <FeedbackRatingStar>Turquoise</FeedbackRatingStar>
          <IDVerified>false</IDVerified>
          <eBayGoodStanding>true</eBayGoodStanding>
          <NewUser>false</NewUser>
          <RegistrationDate>2004-02-23T23:50:13.000Z</RegistrationDate>
          <Site>US</Site>
          <Status>Confirmed</Status>
          <UserID>Seller1</UserID>
          <UserIDChanged>false</UserIDChanged>
          <UserIDLastChanged>2004-02-23T23:48:54.000Z</UserIDLastChanged>
          <VATStatus>NoVATTax</VATStatus>
          <SellerInfo>
            <AllowPaymentEdit>true</AllowPaymentEdit>
            <CheckoutEnabled>true</CheckoutEnabled>
            <CIPBankAccountStored>false</CIPBankAccountStored>
            <GoodStanding>true</GoodStanding>
            <MerchandizingPref>OptIn</MerchandizingPref>
            <QualifiesForB2BVAT>false</QualifiesForB2BVAT>
            <SellerLevel>None</SellerLevel>
            <StoreOwner>false</StoreOwner>
            <ExpressEligible>false</ExpressEligible>
            <ExpressWallet>false</ExpressWallet>
            <SafePaymentExempt>true</SafePaymentExempt>
          </SellerInfo>
          <MotorsDealer>false</MotorsDealer>
        </Seller>
        <SellingStatus>
          <BidCount>2</BidCount>
          <BidIncrement currencyID="USD">0.25</BidIncrement>
          <ConvertedCurrentPrice currencyID="USD">1.25</ConvertedCurrentPrice>
          <CurrentPrice currencyID="USD">1.25</CurrentPrice>
          <HighBidder>
            <AboutMePage>false</AboutMePage>
            <EIASToken>nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2PrA2dj6wJkoWoCJaGoAmdj6x9nY+seQ==</EIASToken>
            <Email>buyer@email.com</Email>
            <FeedbackScore>5</FeedbackScore>
            <PositiveFeedbackPercent>100.0</PositiveFeedbackPercent>
            <FeedbackPrivate>false</FeedbackPrivate>
            <FeedbackRatingStar>None</FeedbackRatingStar>
            <IDVerified>false</IDVerified>
            <eBayGoodStanding>true</eBayGoodStanding>
            <NewUser>false</NewUser>
            <RegistrationDate>2004-02-24T07:00:00.000Z</RegistrationDate>
            <Site>US</Site>
            <Status>Confirmed</Status>
            <UserID>Buyer1</UserID>
            <UserIDChanged>false</UserIDChanged>
            <UserIDLastChanged>2004-02-24T07:00:00.000Z</UserIDLastChanged>
            <VATStatus>NoVATTax</VATStatus>
            <BuyerInfo>
              <ShippingAddress>
                <Country>US</Country>
                <PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
              </ShippingAddress>
            </BuyerInfo>
            <UserAnonymized>false</UserAnonymized>
          </HighBidder>
          <LeadCount>0</LeadCount>
          <MinimumToBid currencyID="USD">1.5</MinimumToBid>
          <QuantitySold>1</QuantitySold>
          <ReserveMet>true</ReserveMet>
          <SecondChanceEligible>true</SecondChanceEligible>
          <ListingStatus>Completed</ListingStatus>
        </SellingStatus>
        <ShippingDetails>
          <AllowPaymentEdit>true</AllowPaymentEdit>
          <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
          <InsuranceOption>NotOffered</InsuranceOption>
          <SalesTax>
            <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
            <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
          </SalesTax>
          <ThirdPartyCheckout>false</ThirdPartyCheckout>
          <TaxTable/>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ShipToLocations>US</ShipToLocations>
        <Site>US</Site>
        <StartPrice currencyID="USD">1.0</StartPrice>
        <TimeLeft>PT0S</TimeLeft>
        <Title>Test Item{Won/Sold} notify</Title>
        <HitCount>0</HitCount>
        <GetItFast>false</GetItFast>
        <PostalCode>
        </PostalCode>
        <PictureDetails>
          <PhotoDisplay>None</PhotoDisplay>
        </PictureDetails>
        <ProxyItem>false</ProxyItem>
      </Item>
    </GetItemResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the modified code to help debug

```vb
<%
Option Explicit

Function BytesToStr(bytes)
    Dim Stream
    Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    With Stream
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write bytes
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2 'adTypeText
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        BytesToStr = .ReadText
        Stream.Close
    End With
    Set Stream = Nothing
End Function


Dim isPost: isPost = (UCase(Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") & "") = "POST")
Dim lngBytesCount, xmlString
Dim xdoc, fs, tfile
Dim loaded

'Is it a HTTP POST?
If isPost Then

    If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then
        lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
        xmlString = BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))

        Set xdoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
        xdoc.async = False
        loaded = xdoc.loadXML(xmlString)
        If loaded Then
            Call xdoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'")

            '**I commented this next part out because I was getting Error:Object Requred
            '**I couldnt get any XML from xdoc to print at all  
            '**see below: WriteLine(xdoc.xml)    
            'Dim node
            'For Each node in xdoc.selectSingleNode("/soapenv:Body/GetItemResponse").ChildNodes
            '   sResult = sResult & node.xml        
            'Next

            Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set tfile=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("/files") & "\_notification3.txt", 8, True)
            Call tfile.WriteLine(xdoc.xml)
            Call tfile.WriteLine("")

            Call tfile.Close()
            Set tfile = Nothing
            Set fs = Nothing

            'Let sender know we have received and processing the message.
            Response.Status = "200 OK"
            Response.Write "Message processed"
        Else
            Response.Status = "400 Bad Request"
            Response.Write xdoc.parseError.errorCode & " - " & xdoc.parseError.Reason
        End If
    Else
      Response.Status = "400 Bad Request"
      Response.Write "No message was sent"
    End If
Else
  'Return method not allowed
  Response.Status = "405 Method Not Allowed"
  Response.Write "Requested method is not supported."
End If
Response.End
%>
```

Should point out that to test the file creation I modified the path but your hard coded path on your system should work just fine. I modified it so that I could use `Server.MapPath()` to map the physical location of a folder I called `files` outside of the website and give the anonymous account the required permission to write to it. You don't have to do any of this, I was just explaining why the code looks different.

#### Parsing XML

Couple of things to point out.

The `loadXML()` method returns a Boolean to tell you whether the XML successfully loaded or not. If the return value is `False` use `parseError` object to retrieve the last error the parser encountered while validating the XML.

In the example above I pass it back as a `HTTP 400 Bad Request` response with the `errorCode` and `Reason` properties as the body of the message.

---

#### Related

- [Answer to Receiving SOAP notifications from eBay api into ASP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257088/692942)
- [Accessing a request's body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777124/692942) *(Credit to [@kul-tigin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893670/kul-tigin) for the `BytesToStr()` function)*

Comment: Thank you so much, great stuff! parseError is now another handy trick added to my tool chest!

Answer (score 3):

Accepted solution is definitely the answer to the question.

But I want to show other methods related with little known capabilities of the MSXML.

This, processing XML request body also can be done in more reliable binary-safe ways without string conversions, possible charset / encoding headaches etc.

[load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx) method can handle ASP's Request object, a Stream object (or an object implements [IStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) or SAFEARRAY of *unsigned* bytes.

from [load Method (C/C++ Syntax)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_1)

> **Parameters**
>
> xmlSource[in]
>
> An indicator of the source XML to parse. This may be an URL (String/BSTR), **a Request object (in an ASP page)** **[1]**, **an IStream** **[3]**,
>   **SAFEARRAY of bytes (VT_ARRAY|VT_UI1)** **[2]**, a DOMDocument object, or any
>   object that supports IStream, ISequentialStream, or IPersistStream.
>   See Remarks for more information.  isSuccessful[out, retval]

Based on [Lankymart's](https://stackoverflow.com/u/692942) solution (thanks for the credit BTW), from simple to complex:

**Method #1** - The `Request` object

```vb
'[...]
Set xdoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xdoc.async = False
loaded = xdoc.load(Request)
'[...]
```

**Method #2** - SAFEARRAY

```vb
'[...]
Set xdoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xdoc.async = False
loaded = xdoc.Load(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))
'[...]
```

**Method #3** - `Adodb.Stream` object (binary type)

```vb
'[...]
Set xdoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xdoc.async = False

Dim binaryStream
Set binaryStream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    binaryStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    binaryStream.Open
    binaryStream.Write Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount)
    binaryStream.Position = 0

loaded = xdoc.Load(binaryStream)
'[...]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome follow-up it's a while since I did anything with `BinaryRead` wasn't sure if it could be passed directly.